# Не происходит обновления отображения переменной из Jetpack Compose (Android Studio)

Tags: mvvm

в приложении используется mvvm и jetpack compose, на экране (View, compose) отображается получено ли разрешение с помощью следующего кода:

```
//vaiant 1
var acc by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
acc = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(LocalContext.current)
    .contains(LocalContext.current.packageName)
Text(if (acc) "good" else "bad")
//vaiant 2
val access = NotificationManagerCompat.getEnabledListenerPackages(LocalContext.current)
        .contains(LocalContext.current.packageName)
Text(if (access) "good" else "bad")
```

после открываются настройки с помощью:

```
context.startActivity(Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS"))
```

после изменения настроек, на экране отображается старое значение (не обновляется), но если перейти на другой экран и снова открыть этот - отображаемое значение обновляется, в связи с этим 2 вопроса

1. как сделать так, чтобы после изменения настроек, отображаемое значение на экране тут же обновлялось?
2. возможно ли чтение параметра данной настройки перенести во ViewModel?